# Tags from `acts-as-taggable` not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I am intending to extend my toDoList Rails 5 application based off Hartl’s tutorial by implementing a tagging system using `gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 5.0'`. Before adding the tags, the application currently supports many user accounts as well as signup and login feature. I’m following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBa2qs9CFZQ) to help me implement it.

I have updated the Micropost model, shared micropost form, and the main micropost form, which is responsible for showing the tags on the home page of the users.

However, even after creating tags with no errors. The tags don’t get displayed. Can someone suggest where the error could come from? Do let me know if you need more information about my application.

Here's my code for the files that I have changed.

Micropost Model

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessor :tag_list 
  acts_as_taggable 
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: {maximum: 140 }

end
```

shared/_micropost_form.html.erb(for the adding of tasks)

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %> 
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Add new task..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add Task", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Main Micropost form(_micropost.html.erb, to see current tasks)

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, size: 50), micropost.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %></span>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <p>
    Tags: <%= micropost.tag_list %>
  </p>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
    <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
      <%= link_to "Done", micropost, method: :delete,
                                   data: { confirm: "Keep up the good work!" } %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</li>
```

Micropost controller

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "You have deleted a task!"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :tag_list)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

On a sample account(some of the posts have same content but different tags, the bug is not yet accounted for)

[image: Sample Account]

Update: I changed my code according to a comment and got a new error message. The line error refers to the `save` method.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: You mean the "Tags: ..." on the Current Tasks section? you are not showing the code for that part.

Comment: @arieljuod Thanks for pointing the typo error out, I have updated my question. I'm referring to the part about the Current Tasks, which are previously successfully created using the form.

Comment: show your controller action too, did you add the `:tag_list` attribute as a permited attribute? Also, I don't thing you should define `attr_accessor :tag_list`, I guess acts-as-taggable-on takes care of that

Comment: I have tried adding it before while :tag_list is still defined under attr_accessor, they gave me an error about saving for some reason. Anyway I have uploaded my controller for your reference.

Comment: change the micropost_params to `params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :tag_list)`, you are not permiting that parameter so it gets ignored by active record

Comment: a new error message appeared, I didn't even know how did the `uniq` method come into play

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186974/discussion-between-prashin-jeevaganth-and-arieljuod).